# Should I use a voltage regulator on a desktop computer?

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-quality

Should I use a energy regulator on a desktop computer?

I would like to know if I should use an energy regulator on my desktop, since I live in Brazil northeast region and I'm not sure about the quality of local electricity.

I'm asking because I've read some articles around the web telling that electricity regulators shouldn't be used at all, because they are useless and even destroy the equipment which are connected in them.

My goal is to preserve the equipment, so that they last longer and I could prevent equipment losses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching power supplies act on input voltage variations faster than simple relay based stabilizers (by orders of magnitude). Such equipment should only be required if voltage varies beyond your power source input limits.

Depending on your installation, a surge protection device may be interesting (e. g. https://www.clamper.com.br/ is a local manufacturer), and it is cheaper that stabilizers.

Best option would really be an UPS (no-break). https://www.engetron.com.br and 
https://www.sms.com.br are examples of decent quality local brands.

Comment: Just bought this one, at affordable price:

https://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product/FR2000PI-BR_APC/apc-fridge-plus-voltage-regulator-2000w-220-220v-brazil/

Looks like it's doing the job!